# Route [/update-user/9] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Investipediaa\resources\views\frontend\layouts\settings.blade.php)

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am editing user data in DB but facing this exception message . Here is my code

```
                    <form action="{{route('/update-user/'.$user2->user_id)}}" method="post" role="form">
```

My Route in Route group

```
 Route::post('/update-user/{id}',[
    'uses' => 'userController@UpdateUser',
    'as' => 'update-user/{id}'
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using route names, it should be:

```
'as' => 'update-user'
```

And:

```
{{ route('update-user', $user2->user_id) }}
```

Comment: Problem Solved . Thanks !